# Until loop issue in bash

Tags: bash

I am writing an until loop in bash as below :

```
 #!/bin/bash


 #check of the out file size and wait file size is reached to feed file then come out


FEED_FILE_SIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FEED_FILE")
echo "FEED_FILE_SIZE : "$FEED_FILE_SIZE


until[[ $(stat -c%s "$OUT_FILE") -gt $FEED_FILE_SIZE]]
    do
       echo "sleeping for next 5 seconds "
       sleep 5
    done
```

but I am getting below error and I am not able to understand why?

```
./dtcc.sh: line 140: until[[ 0 -gt 185219880]]: command not found
./dtcc.sh: line 141: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./dtcc.sh: line 141: `  do'
```

please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: The variables `FEED_FILE` and `OUT_FILE` are not initialized. Please, insert `set -x` as 2nd line to enable debug mode. Then you will see what I saw: The uninitialized variables are expanded to nothing. Thus, the `until` becomes syntactically incorrect. (After initializing variables, I realized what already has been answerted.)

Comment: @Scheff That's not the problem; the syntax will be fine, rather each empty string argument to `-gt` will simply be treated as 0.

Comment: @chepner That's interesting to know. I remember that I often saw things like `if [[ "x$VAR" == "x" ]]; then echo "VAR empty" ; fi`. But you are right - just checked it out: `if [[ $VAR == "" ]]; then echo "VAR empty" ; fi` works as well. May be, this was an issue in older versions of bash. (That observation is actually a significant time ago.) May be, it was never an issue but just the better feeling of somebody where I learnt from.

Comment: The `x` trick is left over from *really* old implementations of `[` that couldn't handle empty string arguments or operator-like arguments in operand position. The POSIX specification for `[` eliminates those problems, and `[[` never had them due to it being a special form separate from normal command evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: spaces.

Add a space between until and [[, and another between $FEED_FILE_SIZE and ]]

You should find it runs just fine.